# Avoid same method signature for multiple functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a js file as shown below. As you can see all the **functions have same syntax**, only thing that is different is the actual implementation. I have a feeling that I can write some wrapper function which declares the actual function and then I can use the other commands functions **without duplicating the syntax again and again**. But I am not able to comprehend how should I go about it!

```
'use strict'
module.exports = () => {
  const firstName = (name) => name.split(' ', 1)[0]

  const commands = {
    s (cb, name, text, session) { cb(null, 'ee') }
  }

 // commands.execute = (cb, name, text, session)

  commands.salut = (cb, name, text, session) => {
    session.firstName = firstName(name)
    cb(null, `Hi ${session.firstName}`)
  }

  commands.bye = (cb, name, text, session) =>
    cb(null, `bye ${session.firstName}`)

  commands.help = (cb, name, text, session) =>
    cb(null, `help me too`)

  commands.noMapping = (cb, name, text, session) =>
    cb(null, `sorry I haven't been programmed for this cmd, to end the chat type 'bye bot'`)

  return commands
}
```

Any pointers are welcome !

Comment: You should look at typescript, wich implements interface , sadly, ES6 does not provide interface support

Comment: I heard of reasons to merge functions where their body did have the same lines of code, but in your example i don't see a reason to merge the function 'head'. If you really want to do this you could have one function that takes all these arguments **and** an additional argument, which will then tell the function where to route the request to. - but in the end you will end up with defining the functions nevertheless.

Comment: i guess then i ll just add a template in my editor.